# How do I speed up my middleman 4 development blog build?

Tags: performance, blogs, middleman-4

My Middleman 4 site has 250 blog posts.

The number of blogs makes livereload so slow as to be unusable (a change takes more than 1 minute to update)

I deleted all the blog posts except for the most recent three and things are fast again, but this isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by using Middleman's [ignore file feature](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/dynamic_pages/#ignoring-files).

My `config.rb` looked like this:

```
configure :development do
  ignore /blog\/posts\/201[0-6]-[0-9][0-8].*.html/       # ignore everything before 2016-09
  ignore /blog\/posts\/201[0-6]-[0-9][0-9]-[^2].*.html/  # ignore everything in september 2016 unless in the 20s.
end
```

If I were better at Regex I could probably make it a one liner - but I'm not :)